# How to Disable Wp rocket Caching Permanently for all pages

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

Currently, I'm using Nginx FASTCGI and Redis cache to Improve my server side caching. I'm also using Wp rocket to optimize website performance. When I clear Wp rocket cache with Wp rocket clear cache option, my website get break. For fixing this issue, I have to delete cache folder. I used wp rocket disable cache plugin, but that doesn't works perfectly. Is there any solution for either remove wp rocket cache clearing system or, Prevent wp rocket from adding wp-cache true line in the wp-config file, or remove clear cache option permanently from WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this helper plugin to completely turn off the WP Rocket caching while keeping its other optimization functions.
I had the same issue and that's what WP Rocket support sent me.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10MQ5yB5tkzUjDJJt9j8TG_1rTrEQAlKl/view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following filter to disable page cache sitewide:

```
add_filter( 'do_rocket_generate_caching_files', '__return_false' );
```